# Compile Qt5Quick and Qt5Qml from sources under Linux

Tags: qt

I'm trying to compile Qt from sources. I'm following this manual https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

```sh
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.15.0
perl init-repository --module-subset=all
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix /home/user/built_qt/ -opengl es2 -v -skip qtwebengine -skip qtdoc -platform linux-g++-64
make -j4
make install -j4
```

All dependencies seem to be satisfied and no error occurs during compilation, but modules Qt5Quick and Qt5Qml (and some other modules) are absent in installation folder. I checked both stdout and stderr but there were no errors.

So, how do I compile these modules? Or are there any restrictions to compile them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Ah, In my case, I only downloaded the `qt5base` submodule instead of `qt-everywhere`.  Qt5Quick and Qt5QML are part of the `qt5declarative` submodule.

Comment: Can't seem to find the Git source for this "everywhere" module!